# expected 'const GLchar * const*' {aka 'const char * const*'} but argument is of type 'char **'

Tags: c, pointers, opengl, gcc-warning, glad

I tried to convert my old openGl code (written in c++) to c, I always encounter this weird warning about an incompatible pointer type when I try to use glCompileShader()

```
char *buffer = 0;
long length;
FILE *f = fopen(vertexPath, "rb");

if(f) {
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    length = ftell(f);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    buffer = malloc(length);
    if(buffer) {
        fread(buffer, 1, length, f);
    }
    fclose(f);
}

if(buffer) {
    unsigned int vertex;
    int success;
    
    vertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertex, 1, &buffer, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertex);
    glGetShaderiv(vertex, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    
    if(!success) {
        char *infoLog;
        infoLog = malloc(512);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        printf("%s%s", "Error Fragment\n", infoLog);
        free(infoLog);
    }
}
```

Here is the warning message that I got:

```
..\src.\shader.c: In function 'compileShader':
..\src.\shader.c:29:35: warning: passing argument 3 of 'glad_glShaderSource' from 
incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   29 |         glShaderSource(vertex, 1, &buffer, NULL);
      |                                   ^~~~~~~
      |                                   |
      |                                   char **
..\src.\shader.c:29:35: note: expected 'const GLchar * const*' {aka 'const char * 
const*'} but argument is of type 'char **'
```

I don't know what this warning means, if it is important, or if I can ignore it.
Thx 4 helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know what this warning means, if it is important, or if I can ignore it.

It means the `&buffer` is a `char **` (pointer to char pointer) but the function expects a `char const * const *` (pointer to const pointer to const char).

Basically it's saying that `glShaderSource` can't modify the pointer or the buffer it points to.

You can resolve it by casting to match the signature:

```
(char const * const *)&buffer
```